# How would you order alkyl groups of this compound numerically?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, isomers

[image: Specific compound]

If akyl groups are ordered alphabetically and ethyl comes before methyl, would this compound be called 2-ethyl-3,4 dimethyl pentane? Since that would be less than 4-ethyl-2,3 dimethyl pentane, correct?

Comment: You picked wrong chain... It's like most common test trick ever.

Comment: How would you choose the right chain?

Comment: You need *longest* chain and you didn't think what really should be in this chain and not be a substituent.

Comment: Would it be 2,3,4 trimethyl hexane? Since the longest chain would start from C2H5 then, without CH3 because that is a substituent?

Comment: There should be no spaces in the name, though.